# AVAssetWriter can not call the method startWriting

Tags: ios, avfoundation

Thanks for everyone.

This is my set AVAssetWriter code.

And Error is 
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 " """ UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=""（-12780）, NSLocalizedDescription="", NSUnderlyingError=0x1c465a310 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}}

```
 private func createWriter(assetURL: URL) {
    guard let assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter.init(url: assetURL, fileType: AVFileType.mov) else { return }
    ...
    videoWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput.init(mediaType: AVMediaType.video, outputSettings: outputSettings)
    videoWriterInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
    videoWriterInput?.transform = videoWriterInput!.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)
    audioWriterInput = AVAssetWriterInput.init(mediaType: AVMediaType.audio, outputSettings: nil)
    audioWriterInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true

    let SPBADictionary: [String: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA,
                                         kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: kScreenWidth,
                                         kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String:kScreenHeight,
                                         kCVPixelFormatOpenGLESCompatibility as String: kCFBooleanTrue]
    assetWriterPixelBufferInput = AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor.init(assetWriterInput: videoWriterInput!, sourcePixelBufferAttributes: SPBADictionary)

    assetWriter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    if assetWriter.canAdd(videoWriterInput!) {
        assetWriter.add(videoWriterInput!)
    }
    if assetWriter.canAdd(audioWriterInput!) {
        assetWriter.add(audioWriterInput!)
    }

}
```

And this is the callback code, I do not know why startWriting is not use, the AVAssetWriterStatus can not be writing, so it will crash and give me error -11800, unknown error.

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if !isRecoding { return }
    guard let assetWriter = assetWriter else { return }
    autoreleasepool {
        let currentSampleTime = CMSampleBufferGetOutputPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
        if assetWriter.status != .writing {
            assetWriter.startWriting()
            assetWriter.startSession(atSourceTime: currentSampleTime)
        }

        if assetWriter.status != .writing{
            print("Warning: writer status is \(assetWriter.status.rawValue)")
            if assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed {
                print(assetWriter.error ?? "")
                return
            }
        }

        if output == videoOutput {
            if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer),videoWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData ?? false {
                print("videoWriterInput")
                assetWriterPixelBufferInput?.append(pixelBuffer, withPresentationTime: currentSampleTime)
            }
        }
        if output == audioOutput {
            if audioWriterInput?.isReadyForMoreMediaData ?? false {
                print("audioWriterInput")
                audioWriterInput?.append(sampleBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 " """ UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=""（-12780）, NSLocalizedDescription="", NSUnderlyingError=0x1c465a310 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12780 "(null)"}}

Comment: Please put that error in your question, not in comment. That's the error got from `if assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatus.failed`?

Comment: yes, the status is failed, but I don't know why I can not call the method startWrtiting. The code is same with any demo.

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons that causes "startWriting()" to fail, is that the given URL is invalid. I'd suggest you to take a look at:

1. The file specified in the URL does NOT exist. (Confirm that with
   `FileManager.fileExists(atPath:)`.)
2. All directories to that URL have
   been created. (Explicitely create them with `FileManager.createDirectory(at:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:)`.)